# Auto-resize content of a new AIR Window

Tags: air, window, adobe, autoresize

AIR's `spark.components.WindowedApplication` would resize its contents automatically as I manually stretch window bounds or maximize/restore it. But `spark.components.Window` class does not provide such functionality 'out of the box': the contents of the Window don't change their size as I stretch/maximize/restore the window, when the corresponding `spark.components.Window.nativeWindow` instance does resize its bounds. My AIR application is required to open multiple windows, and resizable ones. How can I make them automatically resize their contents to match the nativeWindow bounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean the `spark.components.Window`, this is based on the skinnablecontainer so there shouldn't be anything preventing you from using a percentbased layout / constraint.

```mxml
<s:Window xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
          xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
          xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
          width="100%" height="100%">
```

Other methods for manually handling this sort of thing include listening for the ResizeEvent coming from the stage.

Comment: Unfortunately, percentbased width and height don't work with `spark.components.Window` as we expect - simply nothing happens. Adding an EventListener for Event.RESIZE to `stage` works well for **up**-sizing the window. When I try to **down**-size the window, it jerks but doesn't resize. My code for listener is: `private function onStageResize(event:Event):void { width = stage.width; height = stage.height; }`

Comment: Thank you, Mike, now I have figured out the correct way to listen to the resize event.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to listen to a RESIZE event coming from the NativeWindow and then to manually set `stageWidth` and `stageHeight` on Window's `stage` instance. See code below.

```
override public function open(openWindowActive:Boolean=true):void {
    super.open(openWindowActive);

    if (nativeWindow) {
        chromeWidth = nativeWindow.width - this.width;
        chromeHeight = nativeWindow.height - this.height;
        nativeWindow.addEventListener(NativeWindowBoundsEvent.RESIZE, onNativeResize);
    }
}

private function onNativeResize(event:NativeWindowBoundsEvent):void {
    stage.stageWidth = event.afterBounds.width - chromeWidth;
    stage.stageHeight = event.afterBounds.height - chromeHeight;
}
```